# How in the JQ UI Datepicker to show always the date in the input field

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I implemented in my app a JQ Datepicker calendar on its default version, but I cannot understand how to show in the input field always the date the today date to be precise. Now when I open the page where is the datepicker, the input field is blank until I select the date I need. 
What I would like to see is that the date is always visible on the input filed if that possible.

My Datepicker:

```
//Date Picker
  $("*[data-behavior~=shipping-date-input]").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      digest = cargoflux.generateUUID();
      cargoflux.resetCalculatedFields();

      clearTimeout(timeOut);
      timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        if (cargoflux.validInput()) {
          cargoflux.resetCalculatedFields();
          cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
        }
      }, 1500);
    },
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altField: "#recorded-at-alt",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: "-1Y",
    maxDate: "+1Y"

  });
```

Screenshot of what I mean as you see the input is blank in his initial state:

[image: Datepicker initial state:]

Answer (score 0):

To populate the `value` of the text field, you can use `$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, options )` feature. here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  var dtFt = "yy-mm-dd";
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      /*digest = cargoflux.generateUUID();
      cargoflux.resetCalculatedFields();

      clearTimeout(timeOut);
      timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        if (cargoflux.validInput()) {
          cargoflux.resetCalculatedFields();
          cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
        }
      }, 1500);
      */
    },
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    //altField: "#recorded-at-alt",
    dateFormat: dtFt,
    minDate: "-1Y",
    maxDate: "+1Y"
  }).val($.datepicker.formatDate(dtFt, new Date()));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

As you can see, we populate the text field value, `$("#datepicker").val();`.

Hope that helps.